# Testing long strings in java

Tags: java, string, junit

I would like to assign a text which is 10kbyte or 100Kbyte to a string .
In Java am not able to assign text with more than 16kb size .Any idea on how to assign long text to `longEnglishText` in the code snippet below, will be appreciated.

My `Junit` code is :

```
@Test
public void testLongEnglishTextSentimentWithXML() {
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("text", longEnglishText);
    form.param("outputMode", "xml");
    Response resp = 
            target.path("serviceURL").request().post(Entity.form(form));
    assertEquals(resp.getStatus(), 200);
    Result  result = resp.readEntity(Result.class);
    assertEquals("ERROR", result.getStatus());
    assertEquals("outofMemory-error",result.getStatusInfo());
}
```

Thanks,
Divya

Comment: put the text into a longtext.txt file and read the file?

Comment: StringBuilder with n KB chunks in a loop?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what Java environment limits Strings to 16kb? You should add that to tags.

Comment: what is Form class here?

Comment: it represents HTML form. isn't there limitation on http request data size that can go with request?

Comment: @Torben The limit comes from [static constrains in JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#9279). A Java file can not be bigger than 64K. The maximum string literal size ranges therefore between around 10,6K (6 bytes per char) and 64K (1 byte per char == pure ASCII string). (16K if you take 4 Bytes per char)

Answer (score 0):

So what you actually want to do is define string constants larger than 64kB and use it in your unit test. Can't do that. You have to create a workaround.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738598/1047418