# How to convert long xml's string in Json with java

Tags: java, json, xml, string, intellij-idea

I have to convert xml code to Json. I have tried to use this code:

```
public String getJSON(String toConvert) {

    String jsonString = null;
    try {
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(toConvert);
        jsonString = xmlJSONObj.toString();

    } catch (JSONException je) {
        System.out.println(je.toString());
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```

It works, but only for a short String. What should I do to make it work with a very long String?

Comment: So, what is wrong when there is a long string? Exception is thrown? No output? Undesired behaviour?

Comment: http://i67.tinypic.com/or2iog.jpg

Comment: And where are you getting toConvert String from? Could you please paste the full code?

Comment: public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   String TEST_XML_STRING = "";

    Convertitore converter=new Convertitore();
    System.out.println(converter.getJSON(TEST_XML_STRING));
    }
} the string TEXT_XML_STRING is a string of 2000 lines that i cannot write..

Answer (score 0):

It is not problem with convert xml to json. That part (method `getJson`) is correct. 
`constant string too long` java compile error is the problem. You can resolve it, look at [that question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738574/java-constant-string-too-long-compile-error-only-happens-using-ant-not-when).

Comment: so you think that i have to use a file?

Comment: The best choice is to use a file (eg. shortes method: `String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("filename.txt"))` ([source](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_reading_a_file)).