# Java error while creating String object with 100000 characters

Tags: java

I want to create string with 100000 characters long.

```
String ab=new String("SHBSATO6MC1UN8W3W3..........");
```

Above line is giving me a compilation error in terminal(can't see the error). IDE giving me a compilation error

```
Error:(15, 22) java: constant string too long
```

What is the reason. IFAIK, we can use 2^31-1 characters for String

Comment: Are you instantiating it as a literal, or are you reading a file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738574/java-constant-string-too-long-compile-error-only-happens-using-ant-not-when

Comment: Note: `x = new String("text");` is much the same as `x = "text";`